# Could not find function ".getNamespace"

Tags: r

My `R` session:

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rcom_2.2-5     rscproxy_2.0-5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.1
```

Here's the issue:

```
> require(KFAS)
Loading required package: KFAS
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function ".getNamespace"
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘KFAS’ was built under R version 3.0.0 
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘KFAS’
```

This is the first time I get such an error when I load packages. `KFAS` manual says I just need `R >= 2.15.0`.

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.getNamespace` function is part of R 3.0.0. The warning message states that the package you installed was built for R 3.0, not 2.15. The package is trying to use the `.getNamespace` function, but does not find it as it is not part of R 2.15. You can either upgrade to R 3.0 (which seems to be a bit experimental right now) or install the R 2.xx version of the package.

Just installing the package using:

```
install.packages("KFAS")
library(KFAS)
```

worked fine for me.

Comment: `.getNameSpace` is in `2.15.2` (can't test earlier)

Comment: That machine is off line, how can I get the old `2.15.1 KFAS` package? The .zip file, I mean. Thanks,

Comment: I found `.getNameSpace` described here:  http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/.__S3MethodsTable__.  for 2.15.3 .  But it is possible that `KFAS`  under 3.0.0 looks in the "wrong place" for it.

Comment: I found an old `2.15.0 KFAS` library in my hard disk, guess what? Issue disappeared. By the way, do you know if any repository for old `R` version does exist? One should never delete old `R` libraries from his hard disk, no one knows what could happen in the future...

Comment: @LisaAnn: the old source code of all packages on CRAN are archived.  Click the [KFAS Archive](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/KFAS) link on the [KFAS page on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KFAS/).

Comment: In addition, installing from within R 2.15 using `install.packages` should work fine, at least it did for me under R 2.15.3. How did you get the package @LisaAnn? It seems strange that you got the R 3.0 version...

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I don't know how to deal with .tar.gz files under Windows XP :(
@PaulHiemstra I downloaded manually from CRAN because I cannot use `R` console to do it (the machine is not connected to Internet).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That's now a 404.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem installing things in `pqR` (which is built from `R 2.15`). Preliminarily it looks OK to copy the definition of `.getNamespace` from `R 3.0`:

```
.getNamespace <- function(name) .Internal(getRegisteredNamespace(as.name(name)))
```

(...which I just copied the definition from `base-r` by typing in `.getNamespace` after starting a `R 3.0` session...)

and type it into the offending `R 2.15` instance.